# Changing CSS tag not in website file

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS file that I call it like so in my HTML page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css">
```

There is a tag in the file that I want to change:

```
.rt-block {padding: 15px;margin-bottom: 10px;position: relative;}
```

How would I change the padding from 15px to 30px? I do not want to change the actual file because it is used in many HTML pages and I only want it to be changed in this page. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css">
<style>.rt-block{padding:30px}</style>
```

Just add a the different style in the document **after** you include the CSS file.

---

If the `<style>` absolutely must be included *before* the CSS file, use `.rt-block{padding:30px !important}` instead. Be warned that doing so may cause other issues.

Comment: As opposed to using `!important`, you could also make the selector more specific.

Answer (score 5):

Just use a `<style>` tag on the page to override the stylesheet:

```
<style>
    .rt-block {
        padding: 30px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in many ways, bu t here are two.

Add this code to your `$(windows).ready`

```
$(".rt-block").css("padding", "30px");
```

Or you can create a custom css file for the page in question, and override the class, adding the link to the new css file below the old one like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css">

.rt-block {padding: 15px;margin-bottom: 10px;position: relative;} //inside style.css

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="newstyle.css">

.rt-block {padding: 30px;} //inside newstyle.css
```

Answer (score 0):

The last near one css will apply in html.

For example 
1. there is one css file included   tag one
2. one under the  tag in header and
3. one inline style with container.

So last nearest one will apply as it over right other style

```
<head>
<style>
    p {
        background : red;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p style="background:blue">this is text</p>
</body>
```